# Вычислить разницу между двумя датами (записанными как строки)

Tags: delphi, время

Вычислить разницу: `Edit1 - Edit2` и поместить ее в `Label1`.

```
В `Edit1` цифры вот такого вида: `17:58:28.275` (часы, минуты, секунды, мили секунды).
В `Edit2` цифры вот такого вида: `17:58:27.135` (часы, минуты, секунды, мили секунды).
```

На выходе, в `Label1`, должен быть результат: `00:00:01.140`

Делаю так (Но это только для целых чисел):

```
label1.Caption := 'Разность: ' + inttostr(strtoint(edit1.text) - strtoint(edit2.text));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var
  s1, s2: string;
  FS: TFormatSettings;
  tm1, tm2, timediff: TTime;
begin
  FS.DecimalSeparator := '.';
  FS.TimeSeparator := ':';
  s1 := '17:58:28.275';
  s2 := '17:58:27.135';
  tm1 := StrToTime(s1, FS);
  tm2 := StrToTime(s2, FS);
  timediff := Abs(tm2 - tm1);
  Caption := FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss.zzz', timediff);
```

Answer (score 3):

Татьяна, Вы уже опытный программист. Пора научиться делить большие и сложные задачи на маленькие и легкие.

Например, задача из Вашего вопроса может быть поделена на подзадачи следующим образом.

1. Получение числа секунд из строки вида `17:58:28.275`.

   1.а Разбить строку на части, разделенные заданным символом.

   1.б Конвертировать каждую часть в число секунд `double` с учетом того, что часть может быть часами, минутами или секундами.

   1.в Сложить три значения секунд.
2. Вычисление разницы двух чисел - секунд.
3. Получение строки вида `17:58:28.275` из числа секунд.

   3.а Получить количество полных часов из числа секунд и найти остаток.

   3.б Получить количество полных минут из остатка и найти новый остаток - только секунды.

   3.в Получить из этих трех чисел строку вида `17:58:28.275`.

Comment: Да я то понимаю, не сочтите за наглость с моей стороны, но именно с такими числами я еще не сталкивалась. Я задаю такие вопросы  -поскольку мне нужно не для решения какой либо задачи а для получения опыта. Вот сегодня, к примеру, начала читать все про работу с числами и потому и спрашиваю. Простые задачи деление, умножение и так далее ... уже освоила и вот на этом вопросе остановилась.

Comment: Не знаю насколько профессионально у меня получилось, но вот дала ответ на свой вопрос. Если возможно то посмотрите, спасибо за понимание и терпение...

Comment: @Татьяна, не сочтите за дерзость или неуважение - это всего лишь интерес. Вы *работаете* программистом или просто *для себя* изучаете программирование? Дело в том, что порой Вы такие вопросы задаете, которые для начинающего слишком сложны, а иногда  - задаете вопросы с весьма очевидным ответом. Цитирую Вас: *Вот сегодня, к примеру, начала читать все про работу с числами*. Тем временем, в соседнем топике вы весьма доходчиво задаете вопрос про запуск процессов из своей программы. Вот и не пойму: то ли Вы делаете первые шаги в Делфи и программировании вообще, то ли Вы уже давно специалист :)

Comment: @Dima, Я просто изучаю для себя, мне еще что бы быть программисткой :) нужно много чего выучить. А вопросы разные, по сложности, из за того что я пытаюсь учить все и в разных направлениях. Но мне это не просто дается :(. Но я настойчивая и все же цели достигну.

Comment: @Татьяна,  все мы чему-нибудь учимся. Лично я сам тоже любитель. Спасибо за ответ. Удачи!

Answer (score 1):

В общем решила вопрос вот таким способом, понятно что это не так уж и удобно. Но пока что, выходя из моего опыта, вот такой результат:

// Копируем дату по частям с **Edit1** в **Edit3,Edit4,Edit5,Edit6**

```
Edit3.Text:=copy(Edit1.Text,1,2);
Edit4.Text:=copy(Edit1.Text,4,2);
Edit5.Text:=copy(Edit1.Text,7,2);
Edit6.Text:=copy(Edit1.Text,10,3);
```

// Копируем дату по частям с **Edit2** в **Edit7,Edit8,Edit9,Edit10**

```
Edit7.Text:=copy(Edit2.Text,1,2);
Edit8.Text:=copy(Edit2.Text,4,2);
Edit9.Text:=copy(Edit2.Text,7,2);
Edit10.Text:=copy(Edit2.Text,10,3);
```

//  Тут отнимаем все части + складываем и записываем результат в **Label1** добавляя назад знаки (**:** и **.**)

```
Label1.Caption :=
  (inttostr(strtoint(edit7.text)-strtoint(edit3.text)))+ ':' +
  (inttostr(strtoint(edit8.text)-strtoint(edit4.text))) + ':' +
  (inttostr(strtoint(edit9.text)-strtoint(edit5.text))) + '.' +
  (inttostr(strtoint(edit10.text)-strtoint(edit6.text)));
```

**Еще один вариант:**

```
Edit1.text:= StringReplace(Edit1.text,':','',[rfReplaceAll]);
Edit1.text:= StringReplace(Edit1.text,'.','',[rfReplaceAll]);

Edit2.text:= StringReplace(Edit2.text,':','',[rfReplaceAll]);
Edit2.text:= StringReplace(Edit2.text,'.','',[rfReplaceAll]);
```

Comment: Это может быть зачтено как первая попытка, но как окончательное решение - никуда не годится (. Представьте, что в уменьшаемом число часов, минут или секунд меньше, чем в вычитаемом.

Comment: Дельный совет:), сейчас буду пробовать еще. Как появится еще одна идея то отредактирую ответ. Спасибо за наставление..!

Comment: Татьяна, Вам понятны шаги в пункте 1 моего ответа?

Comment: @Igor, Да, теперь буду двигаться по вашей схеме. Думаю должно получится. По крайней мере приложу все усилия.

Comment: Очень хорошо. Не отрезайте дробную часть от секунд. И конвертируйте строки в `double`, а не в `integer`.